# Does $\frac {2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot \dots \cdot (2n)} {1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot \dots \cdot (2n-1) (n^2)}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I recently asked a similar question, but I was not able to use the previous answer for this question.

For this question, I'm thrown off by the $n^2$ in the denominator, as the first three values do not match up.

I am able to get that $a_1 = \frac 2 1$, but I get that $a_2 = \frac {2 \cdot 2} {1 \cdot 3}$, not $\frac {2 \cdot 4} {1 \cdot 3}$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried comparing it with something? Try to figure out something that is slightly larger than that fraction part (without the n^2) by matching up the terms in some way.

Answer (score 2):

We have $a_n=\frac{2^n n!}{\tfrac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}n^2}=\frac{4^n n!^2}{(2n)! n^2}$. One well-known consequence of Stirling's approximation is $\frac{4^n n!^2}{(2n)!}\approx\sqrt{n\pi}$, so $a_n\approx\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{n^3}}$. As $n\to\infty$, $a_n\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

I know that's an old post but here is a solution

---

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=k\in \mathbb{R} \to \lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=k$$

---

Hence,

let $a_n =  \frac{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots (2n)}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot5 \cdots (2n+1)} $

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} =   \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots (2n)(2n+2)}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot5 \cdots (2n+1)(2n+3)}}{ \frac{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots (2n)}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot5 \cdots (2n+1)}} =   \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n+2}{2n+3} =  \lim_{n \to \infty}1-\frac1{ 2n+3} = 1 \in \mathbb{R}$$

Therefore
$$\boxed{\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots (2n)}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot5 \cdots (2n+1)}} =1 }$$